# Spring cloud Stream Rabbit Binder , Single Message Source with cloud foundry instances distributed across data centers

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, cloud-foundry, spring-rabbit

I am setting up a partitioned Rabbit MQ Queue using the spring cloud stream publisher into 30 partitions.Consumer is deployed in Cloud-foundry.

This need 30 instances of the consumer app in cloud foundry , I would like to distribute these instances into 2 data centers . So I started 15 instances in one datacenter and other 15 in the second datacenter

I expected one  instance each connecting to 0-29 partition (one partition gets one instance) , but 2 instances(one each from each data center) got connected to 0 to 14 partitions (0-14 has 2 instances connected). 15 to 29 doesn't have any consumers.

Is there any way I can achieve what I expected?

It looks like instance Index is automatically set to 0 to 14 in both data center deployments by cloud foundry . is there any way I can control the instance index assignments !?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the  spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex to different value will help here , for example , spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex=$CF_INSTANCE_INDEX+15  in the second data center.
 I tried the following  solution using the EnvironmentPostProcessor mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html) and it worked

```
public class EnvironmentPostProcessor1 implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {

            String cfInstanceIndex=environment.getProperty("CF_INSTANCE_INDEX");        
            if(cfInstanceIndex != null ){       
                ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
                Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression("15"+ " + " +cfInstanceIndex);
                Integer result =  (Integer) expression.getValue();
                System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.instanceIndex",result.toString()); 

            }


    }
```

Comment: I would like to thank David Marmugi for suggesting the  hint for the solution spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex=($CF_INSTANCE_INDEX+15 )